# paging scroll in UICollectionView LookLikeAppstore

Tags: swift, scroll, collectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I want create section in my tableview for collectionView[image: like appStore]  the show a part of cell collectionView in horizontal scroll

```
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width - 24 , height: HomeBundleTableViewCell.itemHeight )
    layout.sectionInset =   UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

My problem is when I scroll left [image: show is image] and image showing bad
what should I do when I  scroll paging collectionView showing paging good

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014482/how-to-snap-horizontal-paging-to-multi-row-collection-view-like-app-store